# Clock cycle count count for the same command is not equal in ESP32

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, oscillator-clock, espressif

I am using **ESP32 Pico Kit** with Arduino Ide. I want to measure operation cycle for a few commands.

The code is so simple as below:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long count = 10000;
  unsigned long i = 0;
  unsigned long _start;
  unsigned long _end;
  _start = ESP.getCycleCount();
  while(i < count)
  {
    i++;
  }
  _end = ESP.getCycleCount();
  Serial.println(_end - _start);
}
```

When I run the code, the result is ***13***.

Then, I changed the `counter` variable to different values and ran it again (values: 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ...).

The result is always ***13***!

Why the execution cycle does not change and it seems that the code is compiled as just one loop and the loop count is not important?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the compiler sees what you are doing, and just replace the while loop with `i=count`. The compiler tries to optimize your code.

Comment: try using the `volatile` keyword in the `i` variable declaration  ....  `volatile unsigned long i = 0;`

Comment: Not only does the compiler remove the loop, it also removed the variables `i` and `count` altogether. Or at least any decent optimizing compiler would do so.

Comment: Thank you all. I did it an it is working perfect. How should I mark it as answered?! :)